pytorch indexing multi-dimension tensor with another multi-dimension tensor
In pytorch, I have a tensor A with shape [b, m, n] and another tensor B with shape [b, k]. I want to index A with B. So the result tensor should have a shape [b, k, n].
I tried to do some search but got no luck. torch.index_select or torch.take can only take 1d index tensor. torch.gather requires input tensor and index tensor to have same shapes.

Please try to explain your problem with an example. If you index A with B, you will get a tensor with number of elements the same as B (b * k); you can only reshape that into a tensor of shape (b, k, n), if n = 1. A.flatten()[B.flatten()] then reshape it.

what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

What you are trying to do is get out such that:
out[b][k][n] = A[i][B[b][k][n]][n]

To use torch.gather, you indeed have to have the same number of dimensions. You can do so by expanding an extra singleton dimension on B to have a shape of (b, k, n).
Here is a minimal example:
A = torch.rand(b,m,n)
B = torch.randint(0,m,(b,k))

Expand B:
>>> B_ = B[:,:,None].expand(-1,-1,A.size(-1))

Gather values from A:
>>> A.gather(1,B_)

